# JObject - adding new objects dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I have a JObject like this:

```
JObject grid =
            new JObject(
            new JProperty("myprop", "value 1"),
            new JProperty("name", 
                new JArray(
                                new JObject(
                        new JProperty("myprop2", "value 2")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Nothing wrong with that.

But, I have an object that I want to iterate over, and add them to my JObject, but how to do that?

Like this? (which is not valid, I know)

```
JObject grid =
            new JObject(
            new JProperty("myprop", "value 1"),
            new JProperty("name", 
                new JArray(
                                new JObject(
                        new JProperty("myprop2", "value 2"),
                        foreach(var value in myObject) {
                            new JObject(
                                new JProperty(value.Name, value.Value)
                            )   
                        }
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know your array items in advance why not create them first?

```
var myprop2Items = new List<JObject>();

foreach(var value in myObject) {
                            myprop2Items.Add(new JObject(
                                new JProperty(value.Name, value.Value)
                            ));

} 


JObject grid =
            new JObject(
            new JProperty("myprop", "value 1"),
            new JProperty("name", 
                new JArray(
                                new JObject(
                        new JProperty("myprop2", "value 2"),
                        myprop2Items
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: What if it is empty - how do i check for that? So that i should not add a ,. add the end of the last property

Comment: Are you trying to get the members of an object or a list of homogenous objects? You can't simply iterate over properties in a C# object as you could for example in JavaScript.
Have you considered using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize and deserialize objects to and from JSON?

Answer (score 3):

You can also add properties to an existing JObject:

```
var obj = new JObject();
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); // {}

obj.Add("key", "value");
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); // {"key": "value"}
```

Comment: But it is not just properties - also JObjects and JArrays?

Comment: Yes, you can add not just primitive tokens like strings but also objects and arrays.